# webpack error: File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon , how to fix?

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack-2, webpack-3

I am trying to load the Bourbon package inside my SCSS files. I am using Angular 2 and this is my webpack 3.0 config:

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  cache: true,
  devtool: "eval", //or cheap-module-eval-source-map
  entry: {
    app: path.join(__dirname, "client/app", "app.js")
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "buildf"),
    filename: "ha.js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].js"
  },
  plugins: [
    //Typically you'd have plenty of other plugins here as well
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: path.join(__dirname, "client"),
      manifest: require("./build/vendor-manifest.json")
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        include: [
          path.join(__dirname, "client") //important for performance!
        ],
        exclude: [
          path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
        ],
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true, //important for performance
          plugins: ["transform-regenerator"],
          presets: ["es2015", "stage-0"]
        }
      },

      { test: /\.(scss|sass)$/, loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'css-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

When I run webpack I get this error:

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader!./client/app/app.scss
>   Module build failed: @import "bourbon"; ^
>         File to import not found or unreadable: bourbon. Parent style sheet: stdin
>         in /Users/john/NG6-starter/client/app/app.scss (line 2, column 1)  @ ./client/app/app.scss 4:14-116  @ ./client/app/app.component.js 
>   @ ./client/app/app.js  @ multi
>   (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000 ./client/app/app.js
>   webpack: Failed to compile.

Why does the bourbon component cannot be found? Here is a link to the [code](https://github.com/dimitri-a/NG6-starter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**June 2021 Update**: [In version `8.0.0` the development team of `sass-loader` has decided to move all SASS-related options to a `sassOptions` object inside `options`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v8.0.0):

```
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
        }, {
            loader: "css-loader"
        }, {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
                sassOptions: {
                    includePaths: ["node_modules/bourbon/core"],
                }
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

Pre 8.0.0:

You need to pass `options.includePaths` to `sass-loader`:

```
module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
        }, {
            loader: "css-loader"
        }, {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
                includePaths: ["node_modules/bourbon/core"]
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Seems like you're missing the `sassOptions` object (perhaps a change on newer versions?):
```{ loader: "sass-loader", options: { sassOptions: { includePaths: ["absolute/path/a", "absolute/path/b"],},},
}
```
Docs: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#sassoptions

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, seems the sass-loader developers changed this with v8.0.0. Updated the answer.